Is the Jacobian of this Affine Coupling transformation triangular?
I am currently reading a paper about implementing a Normalising Flows model for image denoising where they describe their implementation of the Forward Pass of the Affine Coupling Layer as such:
Forward-Pass though the Affine Coupling Layer
As well as the inverse-pass to return back to the original input:
Inverse-Pass through the Affine Coupling Layer
The Jacobian of said transformation is used inside the objective function of the model and as far as I understood, the main goal of an affine coupling layer is to modify one part of the input, while leaving the other unchanged as to achieve a lower-triangular Jacobian, for which the calculation of its determinant is tractable. But in the images above it seems as if both parts of the original input are modified, and consequently the Jacobian would no longer be triangular.
Am I missing a significant detail or is it my understanding of the Affine Coupling Layer that is lacking?
The original Paper as reference (on page 7)

Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.
